# Completely log out of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Good morning, I have a detail when I want to close the user session that was created in my system, I click on my logout button and it automatically changes to the login form, what happens is that when in the browser I click on the back button returns me to the main form of the system, and I do not want that to happen for security.

I have this code in the button event and with nothing it works for me.

```
Session.Contents.RemoveAll();
    Session.Remove("userLogin");
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
    Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    Response.Write("<script>document.execComand('ClearAuthenticationCache');</script>");
    Response.Redirect("LoginSMTValidation.aspx",false);
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user is seeing a cached page. Either

1. set no-cache headers on the page to prevent the browser from caching it.
   OR
2. simply disable browser back button after login using the script below

[image]

Comment: You should answer with the code itself, not images of code.